Is the inertia of the inwards pressure of any difference in the implosion type nuclear bomb?
In a fissile nuclear bomb, such as the gadget in the trinity test, uses an explosion to create an inwards pressure to compress plutonium from a non-critical-state, into a super-critical-state.
So you have an inward moving inertia coming from the chemical-explosion pushing the, while there is an outwards pressure coming from the nuclear-explosion.
The explosion have even accelerated the tamper inwards. My intuition tells me, this inwards  inertia will help the tampers job of holding the bomb together a few nanoseconds more, causing more neutrons to fission, causing a higher yield.
I haven't been able to read about this extra inwards push of the tamper. Maybe it has an totally negligible effect or I am completely wrong? I would love to hear you input on this.

I think "fizzle" does not mean what you think it means. As a term-of-art in the language of nuclear weapons technology, A fizzle is an explosion that yields substantially less energy than was expected or intended. Maybe the word you were looking for is "fiss"?

Well, yes, it helps. Also recall that each 'twitch of the lambs tail' releases more energy than all the generations previously together.

You may find Scott Manley's Going Nuclear - The Science Of Nuclear Weapons series interesting.

Thanks for correcting my error you are right @Ohm'sLawman.

@mmesser314 yes! I love those videos - very interesting indeed. But I don't think he talks about accelerated tamper

Great reference. Thanks @JonCuster. Question remains of the effect is negligible or not
